# HTTP calls taking over 4 mins before we see it on Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, cloudflare

Since last week we start to see an odd behaviour when making HTTP request to our Azure Function.

Some context:

- This is a Linux plan, running on P1v3 tier, 1 instance, Always ON is turned on since the resource was created. Using SSL from Azure.
- HTTP trigger function in C#, anonymous authorization, GET request, no attributes or anything else to unintentionally block the call.
- Custom domain mapping, DNS resolved by Cloudflare.
- We are using this is an IoT device and that device makes this HTTP call when a user action is registered by the device.
- For understanding, example.company.com is the host name we are having difficulty with, we will refer to an alternate hostname example2.company.com in the observations below.

Observation

- If we map 2 subdomains example.company.com and example2.company.com pointing to the same app service, no matter which host name we use in hardware, the service takes over 4 minutes before it is triggered.
- If we set only 1 subdomain example2.company.com mapping and remove the example.company.com, the service works from the hardware as expected.
- We used **debugger utility** for the device firmware, the calls go through without lag.
- We used **Wireshark** to sniff traffic going out, we see the calls are made by the hardware without lag but they do not hit the functions anytime soon
- We tried to use more than 10 hardware devices and on all of them it is the same effect.
- When we try the same request from Postman or C# console app, it WORKS with latency of <1s
- We also made Postman calls from the same office which is having the hardware essentially same ISP and the Postman calls go through fine, however those sent from hardware does not.

Actions

- We checked firmware on the hardware and the chip which is used for HTTP comms, looks optimal and since nothing was modified from over a year ago, did not overspend time on it.
- We have tried to look at our telemetry, on Azure, contact Azure support and were able to rule out Azure service or anything from Azure as a possible root cause. Happy to get some hints if we can look into something more specific.
- We checked in Azure Function by trying to identify any improvements but we are running on latest Azure Functions runtime and anyway, calls go fine otherwise except from the hardware.
- Awaiting for support ticket response from Cloudflare if that is simply a DNS resolution item. Can we be affected by DNS resolution on for 1 sub-domain? Seems odd !!

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a programming question, more of a customer support question. Unfortunately off-topic here (as written)

Comment: Hi @DavidMakogon thanks, we do have an open ticket with Microsoft and Cloudflare without much of a conclusion and hence tried to get some inputs from the community here. I will try and update soon on this.

Comment: Right - my point is that this type of issue doesn't belong on Stack Overflow (unless it's a programming-specific question)

Comment: For anyone else who may come here with an issue where their HTTP trigger functions are taking time to be trigger even if running locally, what solved it for us was that making the function static would improve the acquire lock time effectively not causing wait times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it is not specifically about DNS or infrastructure, it was found in our testing that the function in question is a non-static function. Normally when you create a new function, it is decorated as static.

What we would see is, even if we used azurite [local emulator] the HTTP function would take over 3 seconds to get trigger. On Azurite we saw multiple 409 and upon investigation we found that is how it is because the function has to acquire host lock lease.

We created a fresh project, create the function from scratch to simulate the effect and what not.

Finally, what worked was that the function if decorated as static would fix this lease lock issue and trigger immediately as intended.

Before [image]

After [image]

This one change solved the issue for which we have been digging around DNS and other technical areas on Azure.